# Javascript display == "none" not actually displaying

Tags: javascript, html, display

I wrote a basic toggle function that I have used before but for some reason it is not entirely working. The reason I say that is because when I console log the display it says the display is none but the element never disappears. I know for a fact that the function is firing and that it detects the elements display as "", however it sets it to none (and logging that to the console proves it) but the actual element does not disappear from the screen.

```js
function filter_toggle(){
    var form = document.getElementById("filter_form");
    var display = form.style.display;
    console.log(display);
    if (display == ""){
        display = "none";
    }
    else if (display == "none"){
        display = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_wrap">
                <div id="filter_toggle" class="basic_toggle" onclick="filter_toggle()">--Filter--</div>
                <div id="filter_form" class="bg-1D1D1D">
                ...more elements...
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't modify an object property like that ... once you've assigned `display = form.style.display` - `var display` is a String, which has a copy of the value that is in `form.style.display`

Comment: Your `console.log()` also won't log anything as you aren't passing anything to it. Try `console.log("display", display)`

Comment: Haha yes I removed what was inside of the console.log while debugging sorry for that.

Comment: toggle a class....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `display` has been assigned the value of the `display` property of the object (which is a string value), changing the variable will not change the property, instead, you can use `style`:

```js
function filter_toggle() {
  var form = document.getElementById("filter_form");
  var style = form.style;
  
  if (style.display != "none") {
    style.display = "none";
  } else if (style.display == "none") {
    style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_wrap">
  <div id="filter_toggle" class="basic_toggle" onclick="filter_toggle()">--Filter--</div>
  <div id="filter_form" class="bg-1D1D1D">
    Hello, World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much I would have never thought to do that. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks the `style.display` property, but then only sets `display`, when it should be setting `style.display`. Also, there's no need (in this case) for `else if`. You can just use `else`. And, instead of `display = ""`, it's more accurate to toggle between `display:none` and `display:block` (for hiding/showing block level elements, like `div` or `display:inline` for hiding/showing inline elements like `span`).

```js
function filter_toggle(){
    var style = document.getElementById("filter_form").style;
    console.log(style.display);
    if (style.display == "none"){
        style.display = "block";
    } else {
        style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_wrap">
                <div id="filter_toggle" class="basic_toggle" onclick="filter_toggle()">--Filter--</div>
                <div id="filter_form" class="bg-1D1D1D" style="display:none;">
                ...more elements...
                </div>
</div>
```

You could also make this more compact with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.).

```js
function filter_toggle(){
    var style = document.getElementById("filter_form").style;
    // This is a compact if/then/else
    style.display = style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_wrap">
                <div id="filter_toggle" class="basic_toggle" onclick="filter_toggle()">--Filter--</div>
                <div id="filter_form" class="bg-1D1D1D">
                ...more elements...
                </div>
</div>
```

However, you are reinventing the wheel and using inline styles (which should always be avoided if possible due to the extra code they introduce and their brittle nature). The [`.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) function does this for you and works with more manageable CSS classes:

```js
let form = document.getElementById("filter_form");

function filter_toggle(){
  form.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="filter_wrap">
                <div id="filter_toggle" class="basic_toggle" onclick="filter_toggle()">--Filter--</div>
                <div id="filter_form" class="bg-1D1D1D">
                ...more elements...
                </div>
</div>
```